# Passing data in an array from one class to another

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, xcode

hoping for advice on something.

I have a Levels Engine class that creates an NSMutable Array called levelsArray.

I am passing the data to a Levels View Controller which is working just fine.

I also have a Particle Emitter class to which I am hoping to pass the level data.

However I am constantly being told that the count level of the array is 0 when I pass it to the Particle Emitter class.

The array has been setup properly:

```
    **LevelsEngine.h**  
    @interface
    LevelsEngine : NSObject {   
    NSMutableArray *levelsArray;         }

    @property (retain) NSMutableArray
    *levelsArray;  




    **LevelsEngine.m**  
    @synthesize levelsArray;  
    LevelsArray =[NSMutableArray array];


    **Code used in ParticleEmitter.m**   
    newlevelsArray = [NSMutableArray array];  
    newlevelsArray=view.levelsArray;
```

Am I right in thinking I am having this error because I am trying to pass the array data from one NSObject to another and not to a view controller?If so how can I pass the data?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. 1) Which count goes to 0? 2) Where is the view controller?

Comment: Hi, The total count of the array when I try to use it in the Particle Emitter is 0. I just mentioned the view controller as it shows the data is actually being captured in the array just fine. The problem I have is how do I create a reference from one class to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of things.

```
    **Code used in ParticleEmitter.m**   
    newlevelsArray = [NSMutableArray array];  
    newlevelsArray=view.levelsArray;
```

The first line is creating a new array. 
The 2nd line is assigning newlevelsArray to be a pointer to the array in view.levelsArray, leaving the object you created in line #1 orphaned.

I think you were intending the 2nd line to be a field by field copy of the array, but assignments of objects don't work that way.

You can fix this by 2 things.

1) Remove the first line newlevelsArray = [NSMutableArray array];

2) Change the 2nd line to `newlevelsArray = [view.levelsArray copy];

This will actually do a copy, which is probably what you want since you can then go ahead and modify newlevelsArray in ParticleEmitter.m without changing the value in view.

**Important note:** don't forget to create a -dealloc: method in your Particle emitter class which releases newlevelsArray:

```
-(void)dealloc {
   if (newlevelsArray) [newlevelsArray release];
   [super dealloc];
}
```

**An alternative solution is to use setters.**

Instead of:

2) Change the 2nd line to newlevelsArray = [view.levelsArray copy];

Do:

2) Change the 2nd line to `this.newlevelsArray = view.levelsArray;`
Where you have to define newlevelsArray to be a property of the ParticleEmitter class using

`@property (copy) NSMutableArray * newlevelsArray;`

Note the use of "copy" instead of "retain". This will do a field by field copy of the array, which is most likely advisable for containers of mutable objects.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your code,

call the newlevelarray in the LevelsEngine.h calls.

and your code should look like

Classobject.newlevelsArray =[nsarray arraywitharray: LevlesArray] ;

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for the answer. I tried it but still not working. Sorry if I'm being incredibly thick here but what exactly do you mean by classobject?I used self.

Comment: Class object  = ParticleEmitter class's object

Comment: classobject means , your class ParticleEmitter object that you have created in the class LevelsEngine.